# .net core 2.0 prepare all files to publish in one folder in by running command

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ftp, publish

I want to prepare all files to upload by FTP. I tried command `dotnet publish -c Release -o ~/Desktop/toFtp`. Unfortunately view folder was not copied. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x):

> The ASP.NET Core 2.x project templates enable precompilation by default.

This simply means there will be no .cshtml files, etc, as they're precompiled into the published output i.e. assembly for you.

If you examine the published output, you should see something like:

> YourMvcProject.PrecompiledViews.dll

Answer (score 0):

For now I only come up with one liner (tested on macOS). 
`dotnet publish -c Release -o ~/Desktop/toFtp/ ; cp -r Views/ ~/Desktop/toFtp/Views/`. It looks like a bug from .net core 2.0 for now. It is not proper way but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to some answers, I want to combine them. So I can use `dotnet publish -c Release -o ~/Desktop/release/` but add also to myProject.csproj in `<PropertyGroup>` this: `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` so it will precompile all view into dll file. The publish it and should work fine.

Comment: I use 2.1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x docs says I should add it?

Comment: *The ASP.NET Core 2.x project templates implicitly set MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to true by default, which means this node can be safely removed from the .csproj file. If you prefer to be explicit, there's no harm in setting the MvcRazorCompileOnPublish property to true.*

Answer (score 0):

-if you want to deploy Views folder  :

```
   <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>   
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
```